# Uncaught ReferenceError: errorHandler is not defined at file

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

i'm getting the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: errorHandler is not defined at file:

what am i doing wrong? source code: http://pastebin.com/3203ynUB 
i iniate the first piece with onclick="startBackup()"

it seems to go wrong somewhere in retrieving data from the database, but i cant figure out how and where.

the database is as following

DBName: SmartPassDB

Table name: SmartPass

rows: id , name , nickName , passID , Website

```
// change to your database
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "SmartPassDB", 5*1024); // 5*1024 is size in bytes

// file fail function
function failFile(error) {
 console.log("PhoneGap Plugin: FileSystem: Message: file does not exists, isn't writeable or isn't readable. Error code: " + error.code);
 alert('No backup is found, or backup is corrupt.');
}

// start backup (trigger this function with a button or a page load or something)
function startBackup() {
 navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to start the backup? This will wipe your current backup. This action cannot be undone.', onConfirmBackup, 'Backup', 'Start,Cancel');
}

// backup confirmed
function onConfirmBackup(button) {
 if(button==1) {
  backupContent();
 }
}

// backup content
function backupContent() {
 db.transaction(
  function(transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql(
    // change this according to your table name
    'SELECT * FROM SmartPass;', null,
    function (transaction, result) {
     if (result.rows.length > 0) {
      var tag = '{"items":[';
      for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
       var row = result.rows.item(i);
       // expand and change this according to your table attributes
       tag = tag + '{"id":"' + row.attribute1 + '","name":"' + row.attribute2 + '","nickName":"' + row.attribute3 + '","passId":"' + row.attribute4 + '","website":"' + row.attribute5 + '"}';
       if (i+1 < result.rows.length) {
        tag = tag + ',';

       }
      }
      tag = tag + ']}';
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
       // Change the place where your backup will be written
       fileSystem.root.getFile("backup.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
         writer.write(tag);
        }, failFile);
       }, failFile);
      }, failFile);
   alert("Backup done.");
     } else {
      alert("No content to backup.");
     }
    },
    errorHandler
   );
  }
 );
}

// start restore (trigger this function with a button or a page load or something)
function startRestore() {
 navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to start the restore? This will wipe your current data. This action cannot be undone.', onConfirmRestore, 'Restore', 'Start,Cancel');
}

// restore confirmed
function onConfirmRestore(button) {
 if(button==1) {
  restoreContent();
 }
}

// restore content
function restoreContent() {
 db.transaction(
  function(transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql(
    // change this according to your table name
   'DELETE FROM SmartPass', startRestoreContent()
  );
 });
}

// actually start restore content
function startRestoreContent() {
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
  // Change the place where your backup is placed
  fileSystem.root.getFile("backup.txt", null, function(fileEntry) {
   fileEntry.file(function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
     var data = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);
     var items = data.items;
     count = items.length;
     db.transaction(
      function(transaction) {
       $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        transaction.executeSql(
        // change and expand this according to your table name and attributes
        'INSERT INTO SmartPass (id, name, nickName, passId, website) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        [item.attribute1, item.attribute2, item.attribute3, item.attribute4, item.attribute5],
        null
       );
      });
     });
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
    alert("Restore done.");
   }, failFile);
  }, failFile);
 }, failFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the error 
 error : Uncaught ReferenceError: **errorHandler** is not defined at file:
The function **errorHandler** is **not** defined in the code.
In your function `backupContent() {..}` you have used **errorHandler** as callback reference for the transaction.executeSql() call.

```
transaction.executeSql(....,errorHandler)
```

You need to define the **errorHandler** function.
Also you need to consider a scenario as to how do you handle **initial** database load. If you run the code for the **first** time there will not be any tables. The following sql statement will fail.

```
SELECT * FROM SmartPass;
```

The table **SmartPass** is not yet created. That is the most likely reason of the  **errorHandler** being called.

Comment: thank you for your look into it but the database is loaded via the start var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "SmartPassDB", 5*1024); the database is populated.

Comment: I am not sure whether I got you on this. `window.openDatabase()` does not create tables it creates the database. Database contains tables which you have to create use `CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME>` syntax. I have not seen the create table function call in your code. Hence my apprehension.

Comment: thats correct because the table exists this is a backup and restore option i'd like to use, the windows.OpenDatabase is used to open a connection to the existing db

Comment: yes partially the errorhandler was fully incorrect, someone else told me to add the following instead of that:

function errorHandlerSqlTransaction(error) {
    console.error('SQLite - Error code: ' + error.code + ' - Error message: ' + error.message);
    return true;
   }
now it results in a SQLite error (undefined) haha, so im a step forward

Comment: I too get the undefined error most of the time in SQL transaction calls. Only my familiarity with SQL has helped me in debugging the errors. Have'nt yet figured out why the code and the messages in the error object are undefined. If you do get to know how to debug SQL transaction error do let me know. Thanks.